# Magento2: impossible run command in terminal setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile, putty

Impossible run command: `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

return error:

```
[@s1 public_html]$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type __PHP_Incomplete_Cla                        ss as array in /home/czasowe/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/mag                        ento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:130
Stack trace:
#0 /home/czasowe/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framewo                        rk/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManag                        er\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class), 'Sym                        fony\\Compone...', NULL, 'output', 'Magento\\Setup\\M...')
#1 /home/czasowe/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framewo                        rk/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectMana                        ger\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Setup\\M...', A                        rray, Array)
#2 /home/czasowe/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framewo                        rk/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectMana                        ger\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Setup\\M...', Array,                         Array)
#3 /home/ in /home/czasowe/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magen                        to/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 130

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type __PHP_Incomplete_Class as                         array in /home/czasowe/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/                        framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:130
Stack trace:
#0 /home/czasowe/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framewo                        rk/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManag                        er\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class), 'Sym                        fony\\Compone...', NULL, 'output', 'Magento\\Setup\\M...')
#1 /home/czasowe/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framewo                        rk/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectMana                        ger\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Setup\\M...', A                        rray, Array)
#2 /home/czasowe/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framewo                        rk/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectMana                        ger\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Setup\\M...', Array,                         Array)
#3 /home/ in /home/czasowe/domains/mywebsite.com/public_html/vendor/magen                        to/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 130
[@s1 public_html]$
```

Anyone know how to solve?

Comment: Is your website in production mode? I was getting the same error, just tried setting it to developer mode and again switching it back to production mode

Comment: Yes, thank you. Is issues because mode production. We changed  to dev mode and everything ok.